# How to translate rows and columns

Tags: translation

I am trying to translate the GUI of a simple memory game from English to Japanese.
I want to the user to be able to choose how many rows and columns there should be in the memory game. For a 2x3 memory game it would look like this:

```
Rows
2
Columns
3
```

However, no matter how much I look in my dictionary(jisho.org), I can't find any separate words for "rows" and columns". The closest I can find is 列, but it seems to mean eithers rows or columns. So how would I translate these two words?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's [行]{ぎょう} and [列]{れつ} for "row" and "column", respectively. (And [行列]{ぎょうれつ} means "matrix".)　E.g.

> 2行3列のレイアウト
>   a 2-row-3-column layout

Answer (score 6):

To expand on user1205935's answer, appending の数 will make it explicit that 行/列 is the unit of the number being asked:

```
行の数
2
列の数
3
```

Also, 縦/横 can be used to guard against possible confusion, as some people, including me, tend to mix 行/列 up and need to make a mental check on which was which (*).

```
縦
[   2] 行
横
[   3] 列
```

(*) The mnemonic is the kanji 行 has two horizontal lines (rows) and 列 has two vertical lines (columns).